# Explaining machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Is there a way to get an explanation of the model prediction for a specific example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime). It gives you the most relevant features to a certain prediction the model gave by approximating the model locally as a simpler model. Here is a good lecture on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcaAKI1tVGM